# Audit.Net customfields placement bahaves differently between manual scope creation and action based scope creation

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, audit.net

When using Audit.Net in WebApi a scope is created on every controller action event and when we add custom fields they appear at root level in the json. But when we create audit scope manually and if you add any custom fields to audit scope then they are nested under 'customfields' tag. Not sure why this behaviour is different for both the scope type creation.

See the example below:
This is generated by auditscope created when an action on controller is called:
AuditInfo is added through `auditScope.SetCustomField("AuditInfo",auditInfo);`

```
{
    "EventType": "TestEvent",
    "Environment": {
        "DomainName": "IIS APPPOOL",
    },
    "Action": {
        "ActionParameters": {
            }
        },
        "RequestBody": {
            "Type": "application/json",
            "Length": 3191
        },
        "Headers": {
        },
        "ResponseHeaders": {
        }
    },
    "AuditInfo": {
        "UserIdentifier": "",
        "ClaimType": "iss",
        "AuditType": 0
    },
    "id": "",
    "_ts": 1627916814
}
```

Below json is produced when I created AuditScope manually using `AuditScope.CreateAsync` method:

```
  "EventType": "TestEvent",
  "CustomFields": {
        "AuditInfo": {
            "UserIdentifier": "",
            "ClaimType": "",
            "AuditType": 0
        }
    }
```

if you observe, AuditInfo is placed under 'CustomFields' tag. Can anyone explain me why it is placing under 'CustomFields' when audit scope is created manually?

Comment: How are you serializing the `AuditEvent` to JSON? Are you using the `auditEvent.ToJson()`? Also specify what's your target .net framework version. I guess there is a problem when mixing `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json`. (i.e. using the [`[JsonExtensionData]`](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/blob/6a47dac10e192aa6075b0274d594f5f1475c3133/src/Audit.NET/AuditEvent.cs#L40) from System.Text, but serializing with Newtonsoft)

Comment: @thepirat000 Using default serialization, I'm using auditscope.save method nothing else. .net 5. Upgraded audit.net libraries to use version 18. Using azure cosmos db, and using cosmos provider to save the event to cosmos.

Comment: oh I know what the problem is, the current version of Audit.NET.AzureCosmos is not 100% compatible with .net 5.0, this is because the AzureCosmos library used (Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core) works **only** with Newtonsoft.Json, but Audit.NET targeting .net 5.0 uses System.Text.Json, so the JsonExtensionData attribute required is missing. I think I could fix this, by using the newer client (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos) that allows to set a custom serializer. Could you open an issue [here](https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/new)?

Comment: @thepirat000 issue opened https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/434

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed on the latest `Audit.NET.AzureCosmos` version.

Issue: https://github.com/thepirat000/Audit.NET/issues/434

The problem was because the `Audit.NET.AzureCosmos` library previoulsy used `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` which was coupled to `Newtonsoft.Json`, but `Audit.NET` targeting .NET 5.0 uses `System.Text.Json`, so the `JsonExtensionData` and other attributes required on the `AuditEvent` were not taken into account.

Now when targeting .NET Standard 2.0 or .NET 5.0, the new client library `Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos` is used, and a custom serializer is set so the serializarion is handled by the default serialization mechanism from `Audit.Core.Configuration.JsonAdapter`

Comment: I think the new changes are breaking when trying to use Newtonsoft adapter with Net 5 with below code as per the article custom serialization: 
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
};
Audit.Core.Configuration.JsonAdapter = new JsonNewtonsoftAdapter(settings);

below error is thrown:
DocumentClientException with status code BadRequest, message: 
Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing.
Trying to find more details to share with you.

Comment: I think the problem is the same, since on .NET 5.0 the `AuditEvent.CustomFields` is decorated with `System.Text.Json.JsonExtensionData` instead of `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonExtensionData`, so when the `AuditEvent` is serialized using `Newtonsoft.Json`, then the `CustomFields` property will be serialized as a normal field. I'm not sure if that can be solved except by making `Audit.NET` dependant on both `System.Text.Json` and `Newtonsoft.Json` which seems not to be ideal

Comment: Actually I'm talking about other issue which is popping up when I try to set the **JsonNewtonsoftAdapter** as the default serialization handler for audit then entire audit library is failing with the error ***DocumentClientException with status code BadRequest, message: Message: {"Errors":["The input content is invalid because the required properties - 'id; ' - are missing*** This comes up as soon as we start the application and when Audit tries to write the data to Cosmos

Comment: Yes, but the problem is the same. In this case, cosmos requires an `id` property on the JSON, but the `AuditEvent` doesn't have that property defined, so it's set as a Custom Field with key "id", but the custom fields dictionary requires to have the `JsonExtensionData` attribute to be serialized as properties. I will check if I can provide a workaround for the azure cosmos provider so that the id is set in a way that doesn't depend on the custom fields to be properly serialized. But the incompatbility with the Custom Fields will still be there when mixing System.Text.Json and Newtonsoft.Json.